# GWT JDO relationships issue - child of an object from datastore is null

Tags: gwt, jdo, relationship, datastore

I encounter problems while trying to implement GWT JDO features. Let's say there is a `Data` object that contains an `Item` object. In the datastore this would create a one-to-one relationship.

The problem is that when I try to get the object from the datastore, the 'item' field **is always null**. Of course I put the object to the datastore that contains the initalized `Item` object (end of the listing). When viewing the datastore, both `Data` and `Item` entities do exist.

Do I manage the one-to-one relationship wrong? What else is needed? The same situation is when I try to create one-to-many relatioship (an array of `Item`'s)

---

**Data.java:**

```
package com.rafalrybacki.jdotest.client.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Data implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Persistent
private String symbol;

@Persistent
public Item item;

public Data(){}

// ...
}
```

**Item.java:**

```
package com.rafalrybacki.jdotest.client.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.jdo.annotations.Extension;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Item implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
private String encodedKey;

@Persistent
public String title;

public Item(){}

public Item(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

// ...
}
```

**server-side implementation:**

```
public void save(Data data) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PersistenceManagerFactoryGetter.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(data);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return;
}

public Item load() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PersistenceManagerFactoryGetter.get().getPersistenceManager();
    List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
    Data data0 = null;
    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery(Data.class);
        datas = (List<Data>) q.execute();
        if (datas.size() > 0)
            data0 = pm.detachCopy(datas.get(0)); // get first item only

    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return data0.item;  // always null !!!!!
}
```

**On client-side** I'm operating on such created `data` object (with `item` field that is **not null**)

```
Data d = new Data("data1");
d.item = new Item("item2");

service.save(d, ...); //rpc service call

// ...

service.load(...);
```

Comment: I don't know JDO, but maybe `detachCopy` is making it wrong? Is `datas.get(0).item` also null? Could you also check (in debug) if `data` comes with `item` from client to server, or is it already null?

Comment: amorfis, the object received from the datastore already contains this null field - detaching has nothing to do. I've checked it in the app engine datastore viewer and both Data & Item objects are stored properly. The problem is only with acquiring the object from the datastore - just after query call the field is null.

Answer (score 4):

I lost a few hours trying to understand this. 
Child objects aren't loaded with their parents because they are lazily loaded. The `query.execute()` doesn't return the child fields. They are only loaded if you try to access it (with a `data0.getItem()`, for instance). In your case, your're trying to access the child object after you close the `PersistenceManager`, so they're aren't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar usecases in JDO on Datastore and following work around works.
So, if you want to detach datastore object from Persistence Manager in any case and read the child objects too. Better to first read the child objects and then detach esp. if child object is not the default fetch group object/entity.
For example.

```
public Item load() {
    PersistenceManager pm = 
    PersistenceManagerFactoryGetter.get().getPersistenceManager();
    List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
   Data data0 = null;
try {
    Query q = pm.newQuery(Data.class);
    datas = (List<Data>) q.execute();
    if (datas.size() > 0)
        data0=datas.get(0);
        data0.getItem();//call getter for child object
        pm.detachCopy(data0); // then detach

} finally {
    pm.close();
}
    return data0.getItem();  // should return non-null !!!!!
}
```